# Max value from varchar

Tags: mysql

i have a column in a database in varchar format, but the content is only numbers.
I cant change the column to int format, and need to use the varchar format.

How it possible to find the highest number?

```
Category
-------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

if I use this

```
SELECT * FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[" & strCompany & "$eShopCategory] 
ORDER BY Category desc
```

it my output 10, but i want the output to be 12.

Comment: Your syntax looks like mssql but you tagged the question with mysql? What is your dbms?

Comment: @davek, that's a wrong edit. From posted query syntax, it has to be MSSQL and not MySQL.

Comment: @Rahul: I merely edited the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you `CAST` category column to `INT` while performing sorting like

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[" & strCompany & "$eShopCategory] 
ORDER BY CAST(Category AS INT) desc
```

You can as well use `MAX()` function on `Category` column

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(Category AS INT))
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[" & strCompany & "$eShopCategory]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select category from mytable 
order by length(category) desc, category desc 
limit 1
```

(or `len(catgegory)` if DB is actually SQL Server)